# numpy: Print matrix with random elements, columns and rows

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

I want a matrix to be printed with random columns(0, 9) and random rows(0, 9) with random elements(0, 9)
Where (0, 9) is any random number between 0 and 9.

Comment: Can you specify a desired output, please? I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking for is a 10x10 matrix filled with random numbers between 0 and 9, here's what you want:

```
# this randomizes the size of the matrix.
rows, cols = np.random.randint(9, size=(2))
# this prints a matrix filled with random numbers, with the given size.
print(np.random.randint(9, size=(rows, cols)))
```

Output:

```
[[1 7 1 4 4 4 4 3]
 [1 4 7 3 0 5 3 5]
 [6 3 3 7 5 7 6 1]
 [3 8 5 7 2 0 1 6]
 [5 0 8 5 0 1 5 1]
 [1 3 3 7 3 7 5 6]
 [3 7 4 1 8 3 7 8]
 [8 8 8 5 8 4 7 1]]
```

Comment: This contains many random `4`s, but the [other numbers don't seem so random](https://xkcd.com/221/)... ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, randomize your number of columns and rows:

```
import numpy as np

rows, cols = np.random.randint(10, size = 2)
```

If you want a matrix of integers just try:

```
m = np.random.randint(10, size = (rows,cols))
```

This will output a rows x cols matrix with random numbers in the close interval [0,9].

If you want a matrix of float numbers just try:

```
m = np.random.rand(rows,cols) * 9
```

This will output a rows x cols matrix with random numbers in the close interval [0,9].