# How can I make a Numpy matrix with values in a certain range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I know if I do m = np.arange(1, 10), I'll get a matrix with values from 1 to 9 going across the rows. Is there a similar function to do this with values from 1 to 9 that go down the columns? i.e.,

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: Refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353704/numpy-print-matrix-with-random-elements-columns-and-rows), hope it will help you.

Comment: `np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3,3)).T`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reshape` function from `numpy`

```
np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3,order='F')

array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy reshape function can help

m.reshape(3,3, order='F')

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to make your matrix column major is using reshape.

```
np.reshape(m, (3, 3), order='F')
```

More informations:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html